# Apple Notes url for specific note via icloud.com doesn't quite work

Tags: icloud, safari, notes.app

This *should* work...I think...but it doesn't.

If you look at your Apple Notes in iCloud, you can get a specific url to every single note. But you can't actually access the note this way.

Here's what's happening:

On a Mac, using Safari...

Log in to iCloud and go to your Notes.

Pick a Note you want the url to and click on it. You'll see the url change in the address bar.

Copy that url.

Open a new tab/window and paste the url.

Notes loads the "first" note in your Notes instead of the note you chose.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure each note has a different url or could that url apply to all the notes.

Comment: What system are you running?  I use High Sierra and I get same url for each note.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough...yes, each note does have its own individual url. The problem is, if I copy the url, open a new tab/window, and paste it, it seems to load and then *immediately* *redirect* to the url of the "newest" note, which effectively renders the individual urls moot.

Comment: ok, yes i misunderstood.  You must be running Catalina or Mojave cause in High Sierra all the notes have the same url.  Sorry.